# How to show custom message during builds?

Tags: next.js

Currently, when I run `npm run build` while app is running (using `npm run start`), “Invariant: failed to load static page” error is thrown and visitors see “Internal Server Error”.

I would like to show custom message during builds asking users to reload page every few minutes.

Answer (score -1):

You can maybe try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-error

Calling customError(errorTitle[, ParentError]) creates a new error class that can be called the same way that Error is called. The new error constructor will inherit from Error, or from ParentError if you provide it.

Comment: Not sure this applies… I currently don’t have a way to capture error.